# format jq output into a table

Tags: json, awk, sed, jq

I want to fetch some data from below JSON code:

I'm able to get the output using below command but now I want to format it in such a way that my output will look like the expected output.

**Command:**

```
cat dump | jq -r '["name","IP","NAT","location","method"], 
                  (.objects[] | [.name, ."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."install-on", ."nat-settings".method]) 
                              | @csv' 
                              | sed -e 's/"//g'
```

**After using @csv I got below output:**

```
name,IP,NAT,location,method
H_103.109.135.25,103.109.135.25,1.1.1.1,All,static
H_103.109.135.250,103.109.135.250,,,
```

and whenever I use @tsv I get **"jq: error: tsv is not a valid format"**

Can any one suggest me how can I achieve below output:

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Raw JSON Code:**

```
{
  "from" : 1,
  "to" : 2,
  "total" : 2,
  "objects" : [ {
    "uid" : "73b7036d-e8ec-47b7-99b5-19ca89eb5fd0",
    "name" : "H_103.109.135.25",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
      "name" : "SMC User",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "103.109.135.25",
    "interfaces" : [ ],
    "nat-settings" : {
      "auto-rule" : true,
      "ipv4-address" : "1.1.1.1",
      "ipv6-address" : "",
      "install-on" : "All",
      "method" : "static"
    },
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "icon" : "Objects/host",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1674820459413,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-01-27T17:24+0530"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "admin",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1674818326777,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-01-27T16:48+0530"
      },
      "creator" : "admin"
    },
    "read-only" : false,
    "available-actions" : {
      "edit" : "true",
      "delete" : "true",
      "clone" : "true"
    }
  }, {
    "uid" : "7300c38a-a496-497a-b9e3-5701fa081393",
    "name" : "H_103.109.135.250",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
      "name" : "SMC User",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "103.109.135.250",
    "interfaces" : [ ],
    "nat-settings" : {
      "auto-rule" : false
    },
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "icon" : "Objects/host",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1674818341888,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-01-27T16:49+0530"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "admin",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1674818341888,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-01-27T16:49+0530"
      },
      "creator" : "admin"
    },
    "read-only" : false,
    "available-actions" : {
      "edit" : "true",
      "delete" : "true",
      "clone" : "true"
    }
  } ]
}
```

**Note:**

It's not mandatory that the output should be printed in table using jq only. "awk" or "sed" is also fine.

I have extracted data that required from the below raw json data:

**Extracted data:**

```
{
    "name": "H_103.109.135.25",
    "IP": "103.109.135.25",
    "NAT": "1.1.1.1",
    "location": "All",
    "method": "static"
  },
  {
    "name": "H_103.109.135.250",
    "IP": "103.109.135.250",
    "NAT": "NA",
    "location": "NA",
    "method": "NA"
  }
```

I now just need to format this data into table like below or somewhat similar:

```
| name              | IP              | NAT     | location   | method   |
|-------------------|-----------------|---------|------------|----------|
| H_103.109.135.25  | 103.109.135.25  | 1.1.1.1 | All        | static   |
| H_103.109.135.250 | 103.109.135.250 | NA      | NA         | NA       |
```

Comment: You want a table in your console? How do you expect to show that table?

Comment: `@tsv` [is a valid format](https://jqplay.org/s/fSVX1FNo2jt), maybe your `jq` is too old?

Comment: What output do you expect? You put a picture in the question. `jq` cannot produce pictures. Maybe you need Markdown? It can be rendered similar to your picture.

Comment: For a Markdown table I would do something like `sed -e 's/","/|/g;s/"/|/g'` instead of the current `sed` replacement.

Comment: [strahinja/table](https://strahinja.srht.site/table) is a neat command line tool which converts CSV data into ascii or unicode tables on the shell

Answer (score 3):

There is [jbtl](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jtbl) which may produce what you're looking for. If you have this in `output.jq` for example:

```
.objects
| map(
    { name, IP: ."ipv4-address" } +
    (."nat-settings" | {
      NAT: (."ipv4-address" // "NA"), 
      location: (."install-on" // "NA"), 
      method: (.method // "NA")
    })
  )
```

then passing the data through this filter and piping it into `jtbl` with the `-m` option, like this:

```bash
cat dump | jq -f output.jq | jtbl -m
```

gives this

```
| name              | IP              | NAT     | location   | method   |
|-------------------|-----------------|---------|------------|----------|
| H_103.109.135.25  | 103.109.135.25  | 1.1.1.1 | All        | static   |
| H_103.109.135.250 | 103.109.135.250 | NA      | NA         | NA       |
```

Comment: Hi, this is the output I am expecting but can you please provide much common way to achieve this. "jtbl" tool is not available in the device and installing it is not possible. I can pipe the output in a file as you suggested but it would be great if you can provide the end result with much common method like using "sed" or any other commands.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using jq's `@tsv` and the very standard tool, `column`, e.g. as follows:

```
< dump jq -r '
  ["name","IP","NAT","location","method"], 
  (.objects[] | [.name, ."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."install-on", ."nat-settings".method]) 
  | @tsv' | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

[miller](/questions/tagged/miller) is handy for pretty-printing output.

```bash
echo 'name,IP,NAT,location,method
H_103.109.135.25,103.109.135.25,1.1.1.1,All,static
H_103.109.135.250,103.109.135.250,,,' \
| mlr --c2p --barred put 'for (i,v in $*) {if (v == "") {$[i] = "NA"}}'
```

`--c2p` is a shortcut for `--icsv --opprint` which reads CSV input and outputs pretty-printed tabular form.

```
+-------------------+-----------------+---------+----------+--------+
| name              | IP              | NAT     | location | method |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------+----------+--------+
| H_103.109.135.25  | 103.109.135.25  | 1.1.1.1 | All      | static |
| H_103.109.135.250 | 103.109.135.250 | NA      | NA       | NA     |
+-------------------+-----------------+---------+----------+--------+
```

The miller `put` verb takes an awk-like script.

See https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

---

A bit more functional style:

```bash
mlr --c2p --barred put '$* = apply($*, func(k,v) {return {k: v == "" ? "NA" : v}})'
```

---

I'd suggest removing quotes and adding "NA" inside jq, and then pipe the output to `column`

```bash
jq -r '
  [
    ["name","IP","NAT","location","method"],
    ( .objects[]
    | {"nat-settings": {"ipv4-address": "NA", "install-on": "NA", method: "NA"}} * .
    | [.name, ."ipv4-address"] + (."nat-settings" | [."ipv4-address", ."install-on", .method])
    )
  ][] | join(",")
' dump | column -s, -t
```

That assumes that the "nat-settings" object is *missing* the "ipv4-address", etc, keys.

Comment: Hi, this is the output I am expecting but can you please provide much common way to achieve this. "mlr" tool is not available in the device and installing it is not possible. I can pipe the output in a file but it would be great if you can provide the end result with much common method like using "sed" or any other commands.